# I am trying to build the spark to be able to run the programs, however it does not seem to work

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to build the spark to be able to run the programs, however it does not seem to work.
This is what happens when I try to run sample program in spark:

```
 hduser_@ankit-sve14137cnb:/usr/local/spark$ ./bin/run-example SparkPi 10
    Failed to find Spark examples assembly in /usr/local/spark/lib or /usr/local/spark/examples/target
    You need to build Spark before running this program
    hduser_@ankit-sve14137cnb:/usr/local/spark$ sudo build/mvn -e -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -DskipTests clean package
    Using `mvn` from path: /usr/bin/mvn
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
    [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]
```

---

```
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Spark Project Parent POM
[INFO] Spark Project Test Tags
[INFO] Spark Project Launcher
[INFO] Spark Project Networking
[INFO] Spark Project Shuffle Streaming Service
[INFO] Spark Project Unsafe
[INFO] Spark Project Core
[INFO] Spark Project Bagel
[INFO] Spark Project GraphX
[INFO] Spark Project Streaming
[INFO] Spark Project Catalyst
[INFO] Spark Project SQL
[INFO] Spark Project ML Library
[INFO] Spark Project Tools
[INFO] Spark Project Hive
[INFO] Spark Project Docker Integration Tests
[INFO] Spark Project REPL
[INFO] Spark Project YARN Shuffle Service
[INFO] Spark Project YARN
[INFO] Spark Project Assembly
[INFO] Spark Project External Twitter
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume Sink
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume Assembly
[INFO] Spark Project External MQTT
[INFO] Spark Project External MQTT Assembly
[INFO] Spark Project External ZeroMQ
[INFO] Spark Project External Kafka
[INFO] Spark Project Examples
[INFO] Spark Project External Kafka Assembly
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Spark Project Parent POM 1.6.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] Deleting /usr/local/spark/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:add-source (eclipse-add-source) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] Add Source directory: /usr/local/spark/src/main/scala
[INFO] Add Test Source directory: /usr/local/spark/src/test/scala
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:build-classpath (default-cli) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] Dependencies classpath:
/root/.m2/repository/org/spark-project/spark/unused/1.0.0/unused-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (create-tmp-dir) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /usr/local/spark/target/tmp
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:testCompile (scala-test-compile-first) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:build-classpath (default) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scalatest-maven-plugin:1.0:test (test) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:test-jar (prepare-test-jar) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] Building jar: /usr/local/spark/target/spark-parent_2.10-1.6.1-tests.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.3:attach-descriptor (attach-descriptor) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.4.1:shade (default) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] Including org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar-no-fork (create-source-jar) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:test-jar-no-fork (create-source-jar) @ spark-parent_2.10 ---
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Spark Project Test Tags 1.6.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ spark-test-tags_2.10 ---
[INFO] Deleting /usr/local/spark/tags/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ spark-test-tags_2.10 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:add-source (eclipse-add-source) @ spark-test-tags_2.10 ---
[INFO] Add Source directory: /usr/local/spark/tags/src/main/scala
[INFO] Add Test Source directory: /usr/local/spark/tags/src/test/scala
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:build-classpath (default-cli) @ spark-test-tags_2.10 ---
[INFO] Dependencies classpath:
/root/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.5/scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/spark-project/spark/unused/1.0.0/unused-1.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.5/scala-library-2.10.5.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.10/2.2.1/scalatest_2.10-2.2.1.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) @ spark-test-tags_2.10 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ spark-test-tags_2.10 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /usr/local/spark/tags/src/main/resources
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) @ spark-test-tags_2.10 ---
[INFO] Using zinc server for incremental compilation
[error] Required file not found: scala-compiler-2.10.5.jar
[error] See zinc -help for information about locating necessary files
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Spark Project Parent POM ........................... SUCCESS [  3.566 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Test Tags ............................ FAILURE [  0.466 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Launcher ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Networking ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Shuffle Streaming Service ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Unsafe ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Core ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Bagel ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project GraphX ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Streaming ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Catalyst ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project SQL .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project ML Library ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Hive ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Docker Integration Tests ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project REPL ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project YARN Shuffle Service ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project YARN ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Assembly ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Twitter ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume Sink .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume Assembly .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External MQTT ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External MQTT Assembly ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External ZeroMQ ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Kafka ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Kafka Assembly .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.128 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-02T22:46:45+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/223M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-test-tags_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed. CompileFailed -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-test-tags_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: Compile failed via zinc server
    at sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompiler.zincCompile(SbtIncrementalCompiler.java:136)
    at sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompiler.compile(SbtIncrementalCompiler.java:86)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.incrementalCompile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:303)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.compile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:119)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.doExecute(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:99)
    at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute(ScalaMojoSupport.java:482)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :spark-test-tags_2.10
```

I do have the latest maven:

```
hduser_@ankit-sve14137cnb:/usr/local$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_77, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /home/ankit/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_77/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
```

Below are the paths mentioned in my bashrc file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/ankit/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_77

export HADOOP_HOME=/home/ankit/Downloads/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native 
#export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin 
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
export CASSANDRA_HOME =$CASSANDRA_HOME:/home/hduser_/cassandra
#export PATH = $PATH:$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin
export SCALA_HOME = $SCALA_HOME:/usr/local/scala
export PATH = $SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I am new to SOF,could someone please advise?

Comment: It says "Required file not found: scala-compiler-2.10.5.jar". Are you sure that mvn was able to download it? Could you, please, check that?

Comment: @fathersson how do I check that?

Comment: You could look into your local maven repo. It's usually in your home directory under .m2, just use find utility to look for it.

Comment: Why do you want to compile your spark distro. You can easily download one of the many pre-built binaries here http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: @PinoSan I did use a pre-built version: spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
I have even tried with '$ sbt/sbt package', but the still spark shell would not start.

Comment: @fathersson I was able to find the file:
ankit@ankit-sve14137cnb:~$ locate scala-compiler-2.10.5.jar
/home/hduser_/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.10.5.jar

what should we do next?

Comment: You are either compiling spark with mvn or just using a pre-built version of spark and forget about building it.

Comment: @PinoSan I didnt get you? I was tring to invoke spark shell after extracting a pre-built version, it did not work so have been trying all these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Maven 3 if you just had a failed download and have fixed it (e.g. by uploading the jar toa repository) it will cache the failure. To force a refresh add -U to the command line. Try refreshing and let me know how it'll go.

If you have already failed build once you need to force refresh with maven 3 : The command should be (note the `-U` option):

```
mvn -U -DskipTests clean package
```